# Escape all attributes of an object

Tags: javascript, escaping, object-literal

How can I escape all attributes of an object in JS?

```
var literal = {
    valid:'thisIsAValidValue', 
    toEscape:'ThîsStringNéédsToBéEscàped'
};

//Does not work
escape(literal)

//Does not work either, how to loop over attributes?
$.each(literal.attributes, function(){
   this = escape(this);
});
```

Comment: I do not see an object literal.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: You don't? I do. The spec's term is *object initializer*, but "object literal" is a common synonym.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, are you *really* sure you want `escape`? It's an old, deprecated function.

But in any case, the form of the code doesn't change, regardless what function you call to transform the values:

```
var key;
for (key in literal) {
    literal[key] = escape(literal[key]);
}
```

Or using jQuery's `$.each`, since you seem to be using jQuery:

```
$.each(literal, function(key, value) {
    literal[key] = escape(value);
});
```

If you want to be sure not to process inherited properties (although your `literal` won't have any enumerable inherited properties unless someone has been Very Naughty Indeed and added an enumerable property to `Object.prototype`):

```
var key;
for (key in literal) {
    if (literal.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        literal[key] = escape(literal[key]);
    }
}
```

More about `for-in` on my blog: [*Myths and realities of `for..in`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html)

Comment: @David: Thanks. It's odd, normally I remember that order when dealing with objects (but fight against it when dealing with arrays, even though of course it's the same order).

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
   $.each(literal, function(key,value){
       literal[key] = escape(value);
    });
```

Comment: This does not work, the variables are not pass-by-reference here

Comment: And even if they were, this would change the *key*, not the value. @Vandesh: See my answer for the correct way to use `$.each` for this. (Not my dv)

Comment: I'll let my answer be as What NOT to do as its already down voted:)

Comment: @Vandesh: Well, the answer is correct now. But it's just a duplicate of a portion of another answer, which isn't useful.

Comment: don't care for the rep (that much ;))
Correct Knowledge's more important 

#feeling-philosophical :D